# Require/import anonymous function without an export

Tags: javascript

I have a js file with a single anonymous function, no exports or assigning to a module.exports. I can't change this file. But I need to be able to test it. How can I require/import this file into a test?

For eg.

myScript.js (**cannot modify**)

```
/*
*  Documentation for function
*
*/
function (param1, cb) {
  cb(param1);
}
```

myScript.test.js

```
// How can I get this anonymous function here?
const myScript = require('./myScript');
```

One option that was done is to read `myScript.js` as a file, strip the comments and use `Function.apply` with the code as a string. This feels like a hacky approach, so I'm searching to see if there is anything in the CommonJS, etc area that can work with this limitation.

Comment: Is this a real world example? How can _anyone_ call this function (inside or outside this file)?

Comment: i believe that is impossible to execute the function by outside of the file

Comment: It is a real world example, this script is used by an system that reads it as a string and executes it under certain condition, much like a plugin system.

Comment: Can you test it like that?

Comment: You can't execute the function until you store it in a variable I guess, or your use [trailing parentheses](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions)

Comment: As you did, without modifying script(whether in memory or in disk), no one can use that function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `webpack` you can use [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) to overcome this issue.
This is also hacky but less :)

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
                loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                options: {
                    search: 'function (param1, cb)',
                    replace: 'module.exports.myfunc = function (param1, cb)',
                },
                test: /myScript\.js$/
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

src/index.js

```
var myScript = require("./myScript")
myScript.myfunc("myParam", (p)=>console.log("callback hit with param ", p));
```

cmd

```
$ webpack
$ node dist/main.js
callback hit with param  myParam
```

---

Of course if you want to execute like this:

```
myScript=require('./myScript');
myScript(...)
```

use this in the replace: `module.exports = function (param1, cb)`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var fileContents;
//TODO: load in contents of your JS file here (no need to strip comments)

var expr = '(function(){ return ' + fileContents + '; })()';
module.exports = eval(expr);
```

By the way, this isn't really a 'hack', when you consider that loading and evaluating the contents of the file is its original intended usage.